# Arduino com função millis - ciclo computador

Tags: arduino

Estou tentando montar um ciclo computador com Arduino que exibe o deslocamento e a velocidade em um display LCD 16x2, mas estou com problemas na hora de calcular a velocidade. O deslocamento percorrido esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas a velocidade só fica em 0 km/h. Sou leigo em programação, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço muito! Segue abaixo a programação:

```
# include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);  
int hallsensor = 12;  
int contraste = 10;  // PINO 3 LCD  
int iluminacao = 11;  // PINO 15 LC  
int vcontraste = 80;  // PWM CONTRASTE DISPLAY LCD  
int viluminacao = 255;  // PWM ILUMINAÇÃO DISPLAY LCD  
float distancia;  
float kilometros;  

void setup()  
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  lcd.begin(16, 2);  
  pinMode(hallsensor, INPUT);  
  pinMode(contraste, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(iluminacao, OUTPUT);  
}  

void loop()   
{  
  int estado = digitalRead(hallsensor);  
  analogWrite(contraste, vcontraste);  
  analogWrite(iluminacao, viluminacao);  

  if (estado < 1) // COLOQUEI NA ENTRADA ANALOGICA PARA QUE QUALQUER VALOR MENOR QUE 1 SEJA "SENTIDO" ( O IMA PODERA FICAR UM POUCO MAIS DISTANTE DO SENSOR)  
  {  
    distancia = distancia + 2.073656;  
    kilometros = kilometros + 0.002073656;  
    float tempoanterior = millis();  
    float volta = millis() - tempoanterior; // CALCULA O TEMPO DE UMA VOLTA  
    float tempoh = volta * 0000000.277777777; // CONVERTE O TEMPO DE UMA VOLTA PARA HORAS  
    unsigned long velocidade = (0.002073656/tempoh); // CALCULA A VELOCIDADE MEDIA DE UMA VOLTA EM KM/H  
    if (distancia<1000)  
    {  
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);  
      lcd.print("Dis: ");  
      lcd.print(distancia);  
      lcd.print(" m");  
      Serial.print("Dis: ");  
      Serial.print(distancia);  
      Serial.println(" m");  
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);  
      lcd.print("Vel: ");  
      lcd.print(velocidade);  
      lcd.print(" Km/h");  
    }  
    if (distancia>=1000)  
    {  
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);  
      lcd.print("Dis: ");  
      lcd.print(kilometros);  
      lcd.print(" Km ");  
      Serial.print("Dis: ");  
      Serial.print(kilometros);  
      Serial.println(" m");  
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);  
      lcd.print("Vel: ");  
      lcd.print(velocidade);  
      lcd.print(" Km/h");  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Não é meio perigoso deixar um simples IF determinar a volta? Se o ímã demorar em cima do sensor, ele não vai contar mais que uma volta? Talvez fosse necessário um esquema tipo _flip-flop_ que ao ser menor que 1, obrigatoriamente espere voltar pra 1 de novo pra contar nova volta. E de preferencia por uma margem de erro boa.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar aqui

Comment: Ah, à propósito, o usuário (e moderador) @bfavaretto tinha postado uma sugestão de inverter a posição das linhas `float volta = millis() - tempoanterior;` e `float tempoanterior = millis();`, pois como está você terá sempre zero em "volta". Teste se isso melhora algo, e comente se deu diferença, se possível.

Comment: muito obrigado, tinha que inverter mesmo pq se não so ficaria em zero. Mas tinha mais erros por exemplo: float tempoh = volta * 0000000.277777777; // CONVERTE O TEMPO DE UMA VOLTA PARA HORAS - o certo era 0.0000002 - li que o float so aceita de 6 ~ 7 casas decimais de precisão

Comment: vou postar como o código ficou com as mudanças, coloquei a necessidade de mudança de estado para que some mais uma vez a volta como você havia mencionado

Comment: Relacionado: https://github.com/carmolim/cycloduino http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=136786.0
http://scuola.arduino.cc/courses/lessons/view/kKa1Z3K

Comment: tempoh = (volta * 0.2777777) / 1000000

Comment: @AnthoniSilva, vc está pensando em montar um odômetro? caso sim, o ideal é você usar uma biblioteca como a para medir movimento de um Encoder, veja esta: https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_Encoder.html

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de aplicação vc deve considerar usar um *interrupt* pino 2 ou 3 do *arduino* cada passagem do pino interrompe o programa e conta uma variável.

Você pode usar o *millis* apenas para saber quando o tempo passou por um período de tempo tipo segundos ou minutos.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Interrupts

Calibre o sensor para saber quando atingiu 1 metro isso lhe dará uma referencia

Você pode com isso adicionar velocidades medias e outros tipos de medidas.

Comece deste código

```
// teste de velocidade 


unsigned long contaPulso;       
float kmh = 0;
unsigned long distancia;
unsigned long time = 1000;
int enable = 1;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);            
pinMode(2, INPUT);
attachInterrupt(0, incpulso, FALLING); //Configura o pino 2(Interrupção 0) interrupção
}


void loop (){

if (enable == 1){contaPulso = 0; sei(); enable = 0;}

if (millis() => time){

  cli();
  Serial.println(time); 
  time = millis() + 1000;  
  enable =1;

  distancia = contaPulso + [seu valor de calibração];
   kmh = distancia * 3,6; 
  Serial.print(distancia);
  Serial.println("distancia  ");

  Serial.print(kmh);
  Serial.println("KMH  ");


  }


}

void incpulso ()
{contaPulso++;}
```